# Lg smartfone stopped downloading images in gallery

Tags: image, gallery, lg

I have a Rizio and enjoyed downloading images from google crome. They would go straight to gallery. Now i have to view them firsr in the download app. I tried powering off the phone. I've searched everywhere for any way i can get it to go back to downloading straight to gallery. I saw a recommendation to get app scans. I did that but this still involves an extra step each time. I also took out the sim chip and put it back. Nope! I also force stopped google plus. Nope!. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Same thing happens to my LG G3 Lollipop. Maybe it's got issue on LG devices? Check this thread too: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6Q-f5Jyz3Xo

Comment: I tried uninstalling the updates on my Chrome. The bug doesn't occur now and images are now appearing on my Gallery folder. Seems to be a Chrome-LG issue, because the latest version of Chrome works on other devices such as HTC M9.